# Finding the total differential.

Tags: differential

My understanding of this is that it is a rate of change and in my mind I think of it like a vector.. you go some units in the $x$ direction and some units in the $y$ direction giving you the total rate of change for a unit movement of $x$ and a unit movement of $y$. Is this correct ?

So if we start at some origin then the total differential is basically the distance we moved multiplied by the differential in that direction ?

When I solve this problem myself I get

$$(2x + y)dx + (2y + x)dy$$ where wolfram says :

$$x\frac{dy}{dx} +2 y \frac{dy}{dx}+2 x+y$$

Are the two answers the same and could you please explain and could you please explain if my understanding of total differential is correct ?

Thank you,

Comment: what is the equation ?

Comment: arrgghhhh sorry -  x^2 + xy + y^2

Comment: Your expression is $d(x^2+xy+y^2)$; wolfram's expression is $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2+xy+y^2)$. That's all.

Comment: Please edit the body to include the important details --- people shouldn't have to scroll through the comments to find it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Although they shouldn't have to, it's not a bad habit for them to have.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through [this playlist](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus) for a clearer understanding of differentiation.
You can learn about [implicit derivatives](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/implicit_differentiation/v/implicit-differentiation-1) like the one you've tried to do.

---

I'm not sure how you solved it but here's how I would it:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^2 + xy + y^2)\\
=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) + \frac{d}{dx}(xy) + \frac{d}{dx}(y^2)\\
= 2x + x\frac{dy}{dx} + y\frac{dx}{dx} + 2y\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\equiv x\frac{dy}{dx} +2 y \frac{dy}{dx}+2 x+y \tag{W$\alpha$ is right!}$$

Here we've used two important concepts:

- $(uv)' = u'v + uv' \quad\dots$ (used in $\frac{d}{dx} xy$)
- $(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) \quad\dots$ (used in $\frac{d}{dx} y^2$)

---

Now there's a rough way of differentiating it without respect to any variable:

$$\Delta (x^2 + xy + y^2) \\
= 2x\Delta x + y\Delta x + x\Delta y + 2y\Delta y \\
= (2x + y)\Delta x + (2y + x)\Delta y \tag{You're right!}$$

---

So, basically you did do it right. Wolfram alpha (and I) did it with respect to $x$ and considered $y$ to be a function of $x$. 
You've basically differentiated with respect to a third variable. The variable itself is irrelevant in the way we've done it.

Mhh, maybe your understanding of differentiation is better than mine since you've got an answer with a self-made intuitive explanation :D

Good Job!

Comment: The OP's notation is common in certain subfields of physics, including thermodynamics. In particular, in undergraduate thermodynamics, one writes things like $d(E-TS)=dE-d(TS)=TdS-pdV+mdN-TdS-SdT=-SdT-pdV+mdN.$ From this they conclude that $E-TS$ is a "natural" function of $T,V,N$, whereas $E$ is a "natural" function of $S,V,N$. In graduate thermodynamics a better way of thinking about it (using a Legendre transform) is presented.

Comment: @Ian: That's nice but notation is irrelevant really. I could have used $\star$ instead of $\Delta$, the process is what matters. Ofcourse, readability and coherency do matter but hopefully my usage can be overlooked. I use $\Delta$ for sentimental reasons.

Comment: I did not mean the $d$ notation specifically. I meant the use of a total differential, rather than only differentiating with respect to one variable at a time, or explicitly differentiating with respect to a "hidden variable" that governs all of the others. I agree that the actual choice of the symbol is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have no doubt that it was my fault. My notation probably wasn't very clear. Looking over my notes it does say that :                                           $z = f(x,y) = x^2+xy+y^2$